# sms server for ubuntu server

Tags: sms

I am not sure where to begin this one, but I would like to run an sms server on my ubuntu server. When my postgresql database is updated with a new record, the server should listen and take the phone number stored in the record, and send a text message to it. I'm not sure the best path to take to achieve this. Do I need to write my own server or do you use packages out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of getting it done:

- INSTALL UBUNTU
- REMOTE ACCESS

  sudo apt-get install ssh
- UPDATE AND UPGRADE/PATCH THE SERVER

  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
- INSTALL GAMMU

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/ppa

  sudo apt-get update

  sudo apt-get install gammu

For complete instructions see [Build your own SMS gateway with Ubuntu Linux and Gammu](http://xaintech.blogspot.com/2010/05/build-your-own-sms-gateway-with-ubuntu.html)

For help, have a look at the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/gammu-smsd.1.html).

<sup>Source:Xaintech</sup>

Comment: Now if I want this to run even after I log out of ssh, do I use something like screen or nohup or do I deamonize it with: gammu-smsd --config /etc/gammu-smsdrc --pid /var/run/gammu-smsd.pid --daemon. Or does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into [Gammu](http://wammu.eu) - it's available in the main repositories and has wide support for most phones. It also supports SQL database backends (though you may need to structure your database in a way it will understand).

It can both send & recieve SMS messages as well as a whole host of other things.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with my iPhone 5 though, as I found out after I installed it and giving it a whirl.

Comment: I think that's a restriction of the iPhone more than the software; the [list of supported devices](http://wammu.eu/phones/) is very large, and the restrictions on Apple software are very well known. I'd suggest you buy a cheap phone and use that; I've found the cheaper phones are generally better supported too as they have fewer technical restrictions on them.

Comment: I guessed as much. I wish I had found Ubuntu before I found the iPhone!